# Indexing Processing files Xcode super slow build and run

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have the following method, which, if I comment it, there is no delay when building on the simulator or on a regular iPhone.
If I use this method, it delays a lot of time before it runs.

Here's the code

```
func createFirstRowView() {
    let b = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "obj_bg_card1")
    b.xScale = 0.8
    b.yScale = 0.8
    r = SKShapeNode(rectOf: CGSize(width: b.size.width*4, height: b.size.height))

    r.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.midY)
    //r.strokeColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0)
    self.addChild(r)

    for i in 0..<4{
        let bg = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "obj_bg_card1")

        bg.xScale = 0.8
        bg.yScale = 0.8

        let lel = 0.5 + (Double(i)*1)

        bg.position = CGPoint(x: -bg.size.width*2 + bg.size.width*CGFloat(lel), y: 0)

        r.addChild(bg)

    }
    r.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.midY*1.4)

    let q = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "obj_bg_card1")
    q.xScale = 0.8
    q.yScale = 0.8

    t = SKShapeNode(rectOf: CGSize(width: q.size.width*4, height: q.size.height))

    t.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.midY)
    //t.strokeColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0)

    self.addChild(t)

    for k in 0..<4{
        let bg = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "obj_bg_card1")

        bg.xScale = 0.8
        bg.yScale = 0.8

        let lel = 0.5 + (Double(k)*1)

        bg.position = CGPoint(x: -bg.size.width*2 + bg.size.width*CGFloat(lel), y: 0)

        t.addChild(bg)

    }
    t.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.midY*0.6)
}
```

I read that this is caused due to code inefficiency... Can anyone spot my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to separate this method to several ones and look at comilation time of each one, spotting the wrong place

For this turn on the `debug-time-function-bodies` option for the compiler. In your project in Xcode, go to Build Settings and set Other Swift Flags to **-Xfrontend -debug-time-function-bodies**.

Then jump over to the **Build Report** navigator with ⌘-8 where you’ll see the most recent build (and possibly some others).

[image]

Next, right-click on the build log for the target you built and select Expand All Transcripts to show the detailed build log.

[image]

Finally, you should see a series of green boxes, each representing a file or step in the compilation process. The text inside these boxes may take a moment (or a click) to load properly. If you correctly set up the build flags to show function compilation times, you should see a line of build times along the left.

[image]

Taken from [here](https://thatthinginswift.com/debug-long-compile-times-swift/)

Comment: Thank you for your help! This function takes 21 SECONDS to run... jesus... Any idea on what I should be doing wrong?

Comment: @PedroCabaco you mean, that this function takes 21 seconds to compile? OMG. Can you do, what I mentioned in the answer, separate to different functions and find the "long-to-compile" function and then we'll try to play with it.

Comment: @Sander: thanks for that. I also found a 16000ms compile time for one on my function... but also found tones of lines like that: 0.04ms <invalid loc> get {}. And I read somewhere that it could be due to lack of type casting and it could slow down the compiler. Would you have any insights to share on this?

Comment: @EdouardBarbier 0.04ms <invalid loc> get {} as I think is just getter similar to var property: Type { return value }. They are compiling just as usual functions.